# Erro ao tentar criar uma fatura pelo Odoo 14 utilizando um modulo de terceiros

Tags: python

Olá, eu instalei um módulo chamado "Beauty Spa Management" da cybrosys na minha instância do Odoo 14 e ao tentar criar uma fatura de um serviço o sistema gera erro (ele utiliza o módulo invoice do proprio Odoo),

Segue a mensagem de erro:

```
Erro:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 682, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 358, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 346, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 911, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 530, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1359, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1351, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 396, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 383, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/extra-addons/salon_management/models/salon_management.py", line 252, in write
    self.salon_invoice_create()
  File "/mnt/extra-addons/salon_management/models/salon_management.py", line 335, in salon_invoice_create
    inv = self.env['account.move'].create(invoice_line)
  File "<decorator-gen-160>", line 2, in create
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 344, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 1789, in create
    vals_list = self._move_autocomplete_invoice_lines_create(vals_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/account/models/account_move.py", line 1748, in _move_autocomplete_invoice_lines_create
    move = self_ctx.new(new_vals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5480, in new
    record._update_cache(values, validate=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 5122, in _update_cache
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %r on model %r" % (e.args[0], self._name))
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Invalid field 'l10n_in_gst_treatment' on model 'account.move'
```

Alguem tem alguma ideia do que possa ser? tentei estudar o codigo fonte do módulo mas nao obtive sucesso em encontrar o erro, segue a função que cria o recibo no codigo fonte do modulo supracitado:

```
    def salon_invoice_create(self):
        if self.partner_id:
            supplier = self.partner_id
        else:
            supplier = self.partner_id.search([("name", "=", "Salon Default Customer")])
        lines = []
        product_id = self.env['product.product'].search([("name", "=", "Salon Service")])
        for records in self.order_line:
            if product_id.property_account_income_id.id:
                income_account = product_id.property_account_income_id.id
            elif product_id.categ_id.property_account_income_categ_id.id:
                income_account = product_id.categ_id.property_account_income_categ_id.id
            else:
                raise UserError(_('Please define income account for this product: "%s" (id:%d).') % (product_id.name,
                                                                                                     product_id.id))

            value = (0, 0, {
                        'name': records.service_id.name,
                        'account_id': income_account,
                        'price_unit': records.price,
                        'quantity': 1,
                        'product_id': product_id.id,
                    })
            lines.append(value)

        invoice_line = {
            'move_type': 'out_invoice',
            'partner_id': supplier.id,
            'l10n_in_gst_treatment': 'consumer',
            'invoice_user_id': self.env.user.id,
            'invoice_origin': self.name,
            'invoice_line_ids': lines,
        }
        inv = self.env['account.move'].create(invoice_line)


        imd = self.env['ir.model.data']

        action = imd.xmlid_to_object('account.action_move_out_invoice_type')
        result = {
            'name': action.name,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'views': [[False, 'form']],
            'target': 'current',
            'res_id':inv.id,
            'res_model': 'account.move',
        }

        self.inv_stage_identifier = True
        self.stage_id = 3
        invoiced_records = self.env['salon.order'].search([('stage_id', 'in', [3, 4]),
                                                           ('chair_id', '=', self.chair_id.id)])
        total = 0
        for rows in invoiced_records:
            invoiced_date = str(rows.date)
            invoiced_date = invoiced_date[0:10]
            if invoiced_date == str(date.today()):
                total = total + rows.price_subtotal
        self.chair_id.collection_today = total
        self.chair_id.number_of_orders = len(self.env['salon.order'].search([("chair_id", "=", self.chair_id.id),
                                                                             ("stage_id", "in", [2, 3])]))

        return result
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ValueError: Invalid field 'l10n_in_gst_treatment' on model 'account.move'

Na última linha está esse erro, o odoo encontrou um campo invalido no modelo account.move. tem que verificar pq o seu odoo não reconhece o campo l10n_in_gst_treatment. Talvez está faltando algum modulo, pelo nome é algo da localização indiana. l10n_in representa a localização indiana. Pelo que pesquisei GST é um imposto idiano, certamente seu odoo não tem isso implementado. Pesquisando mais um pouco, vi que a empresa que criou o modulo "Beauty Spa Management" é indiana, tudo indica que o modulo não foi testado fora da localização indiana, por isso o erro.

Tente remover as referencias ao campo 'l10n_in_gst_treatment' no código fonte do modulo citado. Ou instalar a localização indiana, mas acho que não deve ser de seu interesse.

Comment: Eu ja encontrei a sulução para o caso, de fato apenas remover as referencias do campo 'l10n_in_gst_treatment' resolveram o erro sem causar nenhuma falha no flow do programa, obrigado pelo apoio!